# How to call an azure ml pipeline from logic apps?

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I'm looking for an example of logic apps calling a published Azure ML Pipeline. By just copy pasting the URL I get an 415 error: UnsupportedMediaType.

Comment: You would definitely need to get a token. Are you able to launch it from, say, Postman?

Answer (score 0):

You will definitely need to set up authentication. There are many ways to set this up and here are the various examples:

- https://aka.ms/pl-pub-rep
- [Authentication in Azure Machine Learning](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/manage-azureml-service/authentication-in-azureml/authentication-in-azureml.ipynb)